# Warning: Identity file /home/sail not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

good evening guys! all right?
I'm trying to access an ssh server using the spatie lib, using the same code in the tinker terminal it works, but in my application it doesn't. returns this error below:

i am using laravel system with docker

Warning: Identity file /home/sail/public/private_keys/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.

```
public function teste(){
        $result =  Ssh::create('fabio', '177.15.0.12')
        ->disablePasswordAuthentication()
        ->usePrivateKey('~/public/private_keys/id_rsa')
        >execute('touch /home/fabio/file.txt');
        
           
        dd($result->getErrorOutput());
       
    
    }
```

obs:
The access data is fictitious here in this question, I changed it for obvious security reasons

Comment: Does that application run as you, or as a different user?

Comment: @JimRedmond 
First of all, thanks for responding friend!
it would be "another" user, in this case Docker's Sail

Comment: You probably need the path to the correct ssh key. Is there actually a key at the path it's showing? If the key is at `/home/fabio/public/private_keys/id_rsa`, when the user is `sail` the `~` will be `/home/sail`.

Comment: @yaakov I don't know how to change the path, when the user tries to access the system, it will always take the docker path

Comment: Perhaps you need a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)?

Comment: ->usePrivateKey(storage_path('/private_keys/id_rsa'))


I changed this line and now the error above no longer appears, just this:
Host key verification failed.